# PointerType event param undefined on safari browser for mouse click

Tags: javascript, safari

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").on("click", function(event){
    console.log("print originalEvent name", event.originalEvent.constructor.name)
  });
});
</script>

<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
```

I recently found that when using mouse click on Safari, "event.pointerType" is undefined where as in chrome it is coming as "mouse" .

I need to do a similar check in safari browser to pass my condition.

I tried couple of things, like using pointerDown eventListener but due to  some limitations(like my pointerDown listner code is inside a different jQuery.On listener and due to that it is not triggering on first click and also only either of those listeners are executing skipping the other which should not happen in my case. As i do not have control on jQuery listener trigger i am not able use all eventListener options for this approach to work).

So after some debugging I found on Safari Browser for mouse click events the value of below is coming as "MouseEvent" which works for my requirement. But can i rely on this value for this and is it ok to use the constructor name here.

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-btn-class", function(evtParam){

 if(evtParam.originalEvent && evtParam.originalEvent.constructor && 
    evtParam.originalEvent.constructor.name === "MouseEvent"){
    //do my logic
}
```

})

Comment: Why are you looking at this property exactly? Neither Safari nor Firefox do treat click events as PointerEvent yet, so checking the `pointerType` might be difficult in there. But you might get more chance looking the other way around, i.e `if(event instanceof PointerEvent) { /* PointerEvent logic */ } else { "bare" MouseEvent logic }`

Comment: I verified the property and observed, for both safari and chrome it is treated as mouseevent and whereas in chrome and IE it is treated as pointerEvent. Added a snippet for it. You can check in different browsers the value for this property.

Comment: But why are you looking at this property? What do you want to do differently based on the pointerType value?

Comment: I am looking at this value for mouseclicks vs keyboard hits. I have to trigger different events based on the type of click.

Comment: So what you really need is a way to tell that, which is independent on the browser having implemented *click event -> PointerEvent*. Maybe (depending on what should fall in both categories), adding a simple keydown event would be enough, maybe, if you need to handle other synthetic clicks, checking for `evt.pageX === 0` is good enough?